# $location.path not redirecting in Android (phonegap, cordova)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Could somebody please help me and give me any idea or pointers as to why my Hybrid App (phonegap cordova) is not redirecting in Android. It works completly fine in Ripple, no warnings, no errors, however when using the app in an emulator or an android device the app just load the page, it works and everything until I click the button to redirect the user to another page it just doesn't do it.
I already have tried everything I could find, I tried using:

```
$location.path().replace();
//also
$location.url();

//also tried adding after that line of code this:
if (!$scope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();

//also this variant:
if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();

//this one too:
$location.reload();
```

as well as the suggestions in this post "[AngularJS and PhoneGap: $location.path causes subsequent tempateUrl lookup to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974097/angularjs-and-phonegap-location-path-causes-subsequent-tempateurl-lookup-to-fa)".
I checked the obvious too like misspell and made sure to inject $location to my controller, references to files and so on, and still it doesn't work on android.
I don't really know what else to do, here is a piece of the code:

```
if(window.innerWidth > 579){
    $location.path('/findInfo' + '/' + docID+ '/' + userID);
}
else{
    DB.getInfo(docID, userID)
        .then(function(info){
            $rootScope.myInfo = info;
            $location.path('/docDetails');
        });
}
```

The DB.getInfo() is a custom service and it is working correctly, also I had doubts about the "window.innerWidth" so I tried redirecting directly without evaluating the if-else statements and that didn't work either. Any suggestions or advices would be more than welcomed.
Thank you in advance!