# Close a child window in an Android app made with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I'm coding an Android app with Angularjs and cordova, but I have a problem:
For an oauth call I need to open a new window, go to the withings site and when I come on my callback url close the window.

I have tried to use setInterval (or $interval) to check every 2 seconds if I reveived the infos by a call to my API. It works fine on a computer in chrome but when I compile the app with Cordova I never enter in the loop.

So I tried to catch an event or $watch on the url of my new window but I execute only once my function at the first url change even if my call to the API result an error.

This is my last code but I tried a lot of different tests :

```
var newWindow = $window.open(result.res);
var unwatch = $scope.$watch(window.location, function() {
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(result) {
        newWindow.close();
        unwatch();
        $location.path('/tab/dash');
    })
    .error(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

If you have any idea to make this work, would be very happy.

Thanks by advance !

Comment: instead of watch you can listen `$locationChangeStart` or $locationChangeSuccess`

Comment: I also tried this but that's not working.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974097/angularjs-and-phonegap-location-path-causes-subsequent-tempateurl-lookup-to-fa

Comment: I think it can't apply to my app.

Comment: your app does have html5mode enable?

Comment: yes I have $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and <base href="/"> in my index.html. But even in my laptop browser $locationChangeStart doesn't work.

Comment: try setting `true` option inside you $watch to watch object deep copy OR use `$window.on('hashchange', function() {
  //.. work ..
});` don't forget to add $window dependency

Comment: I tested exactly what you say for html5mode, and for you last comment but nothing work... I also try to make a loop function who work fine in chrome but only exec once on android... 
`var loopVerifWithings = function() {
    $http.get(url)
          .success(function(result) {
              console.log("loop");
          })
          .error(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
              loopVerifWithings();
          });
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution:

I install the cordova plugin inAppBrowser and use this code

```
var windowWithings = $window.open(result.res, '_blank', 'location=no');
    windowWithings.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
        $http.get(url)
        .success(function(result) {
            windowWithings.close();
            $location.path('/tab/dash');
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

Be careful if you don't add 'location=no' in open it won't work.

Comment: Hello @Jowy . i am having similar type of case , but what i want is to close window automatically  at some specific url and get back to application screen based on success or failure, so is there any way to achieve this.